# Rails session doesn't persist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I can't get Rails sessions to persist, both on a local environment and an external staging environment. Right now I'm just doing something basic, like `session[:cart_id]=1` in one of my controllers. If I reload the page the session comes up empty `{}`. I must be missing something basic because I can't find anything online about this being common.

**UPDATE 1**

Even the simplest code shows sessions not persisting, for example I can do something as simple as `session[:counter] = session[:counter].to_i + 1` in my action, and then `= debug session` in my view, and every time I refresh the browser I get:

`{} {"session_id"=>"280031b7eb3b4bf612da85acc8815b3b", "counter"=>1}`

and a new `session_id` is generated each time.

**UPDATE 2**

I removed the `:domain => :all` option from my session store and things look better, but still not persisting. Now the `session_id` is generating only once, so that is persisting. But if I store an integer inside the session it still isn't persisting to the next request.

Comment: whats your rails version and the controller code?

Comment: Have you disabled cookies in your browser?

Comment: Have you changed the configuration for the sessions? It that application migrated from Rails 2 to 3 or further to Rails 3.1?

Comment: That's definitely not common - just tested in new app that this persists.

Comment: rails 3.0.9, updated my original post with some code, and I never changed the default session store: `Web::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_web_session', :domain => :all`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and it was driving me nuts.

It turned out that I had a `protect_from_forgery` in my `ApplicationController` which silently replaced the session with a `NullSession`.

I noticed this when I ran `raise session.class.inspect`.

Using `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` instead reveals the underlying problem properly.

Comment: What is the fix? I am getting RuntimeError: ActionDispatch::Request::Session when I ran inspect.